# NodeJS y Ejs : "variable" is not defined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

He querido resolver este problema por dias pero stackoverflow me rechazaba la pregunta, asi que espero no suceda de nuevo. En app.js trabajo con un npm para obtener informacion de un video de youtube, el problema es que cuando intento pasar informacion clave como Titulo y Miniatura a mi archivo index.ejs me tira error de datos is not defined, agradecere mucho su ayuda.

**app.js**

```
    const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const youtubeid = require("get-youtube-id")
const youtubeinfo = require("yt-scraper")
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs")
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core")
const path = require('path')
const app = express()




app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views')) 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.render("index")
})



app.post("/convert",(req,res) => {
    
    var url = req.body.url
    var data = youtubeinfo.videoInfo(url,
        options = { detailedChannelData: true } )
        console.log(data)
        
        
        data.then(data => {
            
            console.log("=== VIDEO INFO ===")
            console.log(data)
            res.render("index", {datos:data})
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("=== ERROR ===")
            console.log(err)
            console.log("error")
            res.render("error")
        })
        
                
            
                                                                                           
    })            
                   
app.listen(5000, ()=> {
    console.log("server iniciado en puerto 5000")
})
```

**index.ejs**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Descargar Videos y Musica de Youtube y mas</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="encabezado">
            <nav class="navegacion">
                <li class="li1">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <span>
                            "  Redes "
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="li2">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <span>
                            " Contacto " 
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="li3">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <span>
                            "   Mas  " 
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </nav>
            
        </header>
        <main>
            
            <div class="main-div">
                <h1 class="main-titulo">
                    Youtube MP3 Y MP4
                </h1>
                <form action="/convert" method="POST" class="contenedor-formulario">
                    
                    <input type="search" name="url" placeholder="Yourube URL" class="url-input">
                    <button class="convertir">CLICK ME</button>
                    <img src="<%=datos.thumbnails[0].url%>" alt="" class="miniatura">
                    <h1 class="titulo-video" target="_blank" href="<%=datos.url%>">
                    <span><%=datos.title%></span>
                    </h1>
                    
                   
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**error.ejs**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error al convertir :(</h1>
    <h2>¿A que se debe esto?</h2>
    <p>Intentaste introducir una Url invalida</p>
    <br>
    <p>Intentaste introducir un Url de Youtube Short por lo que por el momento no es admitido (pagina aun en desarrollo)</p>
    <br>
    <p>El Url ingresado no pertenece a la plataforma de Youtube</p>
    <img src="" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

**estilo.css**

```
*{ 
    margin: 0;
}

body{ 
    background: rgb(107, 62, 128) ;
    font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
}

.navegacion{ 
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    background-color: #363532;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    text-decoration: none;

}

li { 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: #FFEFD0;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.link{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: none;
    color: black;
}

.link:hover{ 
    color: white;
}

.li1{ 
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}

.li2{ 
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}

.li3{ 
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}


.li1:hover{ 
    background: rgb(255, 198, 198);
    color: white;
    top: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.li2:hover{ 
    background: rgb(255, 198, 198);
    color: white;
    top: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.li3:hover{ 
    background: rgb(255, 198, 198);
    color: white;
    top: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.main-titulo{ 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.main-div{ 
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 100%;
    
}

.url-input{ 
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF4DF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 480px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.contenedor-formulario{ 
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 ;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFEFD0;
    top: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 480px ;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 460px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 515px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 460px ;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 440px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 515px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 440px ;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 420px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 475px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 420px ;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 400px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 460px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 400px ;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 380px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 438px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 380px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 360px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 416px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 360px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 340px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 404px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 330px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 310px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 365px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 310px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 290px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 345px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 290px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 270px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 330px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 270px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 250px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 310px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 250px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 230px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 286px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 230px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 210px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 286px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 230px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 210px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 266px){ 
    .contenedor-formulario{ 
        width: 210px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }

    .url-input{ 
        width: 190px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 470px){ 
    .navegacion{ 
        padding: 14%;
        margin: auto;
        letter-spacing: 30px;
    }
    .a
    { 
        padding: 14%;
        margin: auto;
        letter-spacing: 30px;
    }
}


.convertir{
    padding: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 87%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5%;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}
.convertir:hover{
    top: 89%;
    background: rgb(255, 198, 198);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.pie-pagina{ 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #363532;
    
}

.imagen{ 
    position: fixed;
    opacity: .5;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.miniatura {
    width: 50%;
}


.titulo-video{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME EJECUTA**

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\views\index.ejs:51
    49|                     <input type="search" name="url" placeholder="Yourube URL" class="url-input">

    50|                     <button class="convertir">CLICK ME</button>

 >> 51|                     <img src="<%=datos.thumbnails[0].url%>" alt="" class="miniatura">

    52|                     <h1 class="titulo-video" target="_blank" href="<%=datos.url%>">

    53|                     <span><%=datos.title%></span>

    54|                     </h1>


datos is not defined
    at eval ("C:\\Users\\ROYER\\Desktop\\practica\\views\\index.ejs":12:25)
    at index (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\app.js:20:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

su ayuda sera apreciada, porque ando loco que no puedo y no se porque me sale ese error :(

Answer (score 0):

Al renderizar tiene que enviar las variables de contexto en `get('/')`

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    const datos = { ... } // los datos que quiera renderizar en la vista
    res.render("index", datos)
})
```

Dele una mirada a como pasar datos a Vistas y Parciales en ejs

Comment: ese es en caso cuando recien inicia, pero en app.post('/convert') ahi es donde tengo que hacer una peticion para que pueda renderizar lo que he generado en  data.then(data => {
            
            console.log("=== VIDEO INFO ===")
            console.log(data)
            const datos = {id, title,thumbnails}
            res.render("index", {datos:datos})